# Google maps becomes slow when customized marker styles

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

Using google-maps for my angular2 project, I have following marker object for my map -

```
private defaultMarkerStyle = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 6,
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: '#5A7793',
        strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
        strokeWeight: 2,
    };
let markerOnMap = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            title: marker.name,
            icon: this.defaultMarkerStyle, // <- Removing this line works fine!!??
            map: this.googlemap,
            visible: true,
        });
```

when the map loads more than 1000 markers, the zoom in / out actions become slow and has some lag.

but when I remove the icon property with map,it works all fine (see the comment in above example)

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? If yes then please share (:

Comment: @Anss  I decided to implement clustering to make map perform well when loaded with lots of data.

Comment: In my angular 4 app it was a third party table that caused the pins to render slow, replacing it with a simple table solved the problem, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Google's path based markers have a major performance issue. A bug has already filed for this issue, but they have yet to resolve it. A work around is to use a standard marker with an image based icon. Obviously, if you need dynamically generated icons, this solution requires a little additional work. To generate a dynamic icon, you need to generate an image and convert it to an image data uri. E.g. The following code can be used to generate a circle icon that does not have a performance issue. This solution works for browsers that support svg images as data URIs.

```js
function CircleIcon(options) {
   let {
      scale,
      fillOpacity = 1.0, 
      fillColor = '#000000', 
      strokeColor = '#000000',
      strokeWeight = 1,
   } = options;

   let diameter = 2 * scale;

   let svg = btoa(`
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${diameter}px" height="${diameter}px">
         <circle cx="${scale}" cy="${scale}" fill="${fillColor}" fill-opacity="${fillOpacity}" stroke="${strokeColor}" stroke-width="${strokeWeight}px"/>
      </svg>
   `);

   let icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + svg,
      new google.maps.Size(diameter, diameter, 'px', 'px'),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(scale, scale)
   )

   return icon;
}
```

You would then use the icon as follows:

```js
this.defaultMarkerStyle = CircleIcon({
   scale: 6,
   fillOpacity: 0.8,
   fillColor: '#5A7793',
   strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
   strokeWeight: 2,
});

let markerOnMap = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
   title: marker.name,
   icon: this.defaultMarkerStyle,
   map: this.googlemap,
   visible: true,
});
```